# Access 2010 Query by Form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm a beginner **trying to add a text box to an Access 2010 form where the number entered into the text box controls the data displayed on the form**.  I think Query by Form may be the right technique, but I'm unsure.  I have information from multiple tables pulled together with a simple query.  What is the best way to accomplish this task?  I appreciate all suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather broad, and I think you should get a good book on MS Access to figure out yourself... but let me give you some pointers.

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a form with a text box and a subform which shows the data filtered by the value you input in your text box. I'm kinda rusty with my Access VBA, but it should go with something like this:

First, let's say your text box is called `txtFilter`. From the properties window, look for the "AfterUpdate" event. Add the following code to the event:

```vb
private sub txtFilter_AfterUpdate() ' This is auto-generated
    dim strSQL as String
    strSQL = "select * from [your_table] " & _
             "where [your_table].[some_field] = '" & txtFilter &"'"
    frm_yourSubForm.rowSource = strSQL
    frm_yourSubForm.refresh
    frm_yourSubForm.requery
end sub ' This is also auto-generated
```

Comment: Thanks @Barranka for the feedback!  I do not currently have a subform, but will try that approach.  I was previously setting my query criteria to filter by the text box entry data, but was unaware of the coding for the AfterUpdate event.  I am clearly in over my head, but I appreciate your time!

Comment: @J-B well, you can put that code on a command button `OnClic` event... anyway, you *must* call the `Refresh` or `Requery` method at some point to force the data to be refreshed